# Read multiple xml file from a folder using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

I am very new in coding in Python, and there is an issue I have been trying to solve for some hours:

I have 1600+ xml files (0000.xml, 0001.xml, etc) need to be parsed in order to do a text mining project.
But an error has occurred, when I have the following code:

```
from os import listdir, path 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

mypath = '../project/content' 
files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if f.endswith('.xml')]

for file in files:    
    tree = ET.parse("../project/content/"+file)
    root = tree.getroot()
```

The error message is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-13-cdc3ee6c3989>", line 6, in <module>
    tree = ET.parse("../project/content/"+file)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1196, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 597, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)

  File "<string>", line unknown ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

where did I make mistakes?

Also, I want to only extract the text from one element of each xml files, is it sufficient that I simply attach this line to the code? and moreover, how can I save each of the results to txt files?

```
maintext = root.find("mainText").text
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Often if you search for the Exception message (`ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0`) , you will find many SO Q&A's which may point you in the right direction. It is possible that the file it is trying to parse is *malformed* or maybe even an empty file. If you want to just skip those, [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and maybe just print the filename in the except suite then you can look at them later.

Comment: Instead of printing filenames that produce an Exception, you could also collect them in a list or write them to an error file - with the intent of possibly *manually* looking at them later.

Comment: `...is it sufficient that I simply attach this line to the code?` - Try it in the shell with some test *data*.... `... how can I save each of the results to txt files?` - [Reading and writing files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: Thank you! I have found that one of my xml file is empty. So after I removed it, it worked without error anymore! Also the element I wanted to extract worked as well like I posted. However, I have problems about saving the result as txt files, as I can only save as xml files         output = codecs.open(file,"w","utf-8")
    output.write(content)
    output.close()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to create path elements is using join:

Add print messages to the code before you try and create the tree.

Is the XML you try parse valid?

Once you solve the parsing issue you can use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) in order to parse many files at the same time.

```
from os import listdir, path
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

mypath = '../project/content'
files = [path.join(mypath, f) for f in listdir(mypath) if f.endswith('.xml')]

for file in files:
    print(file)
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()
```

Comment: “Use multiprocessing..” good heavens the OP has enough problems getitng basic file read/parse working to not need over-complicating with possibly completely unneccessary use of multiprocessing.

Comment: Thank you! the code is working for me! However, I do not know how to save them as txt file instead of xml?